Websocket vs SNS in EKS Containers
This is more of an architectural question so apologies if this is not a right fit.
Scenario:
The application is split in two separate containerized application in an on-prem data center, lets say UI and Queue. Queue emits an event to the other application and the UI is populated based on the subscription from Queue. The applications are scheduled to move to Amazon EKS.
Question:

What is a better solution between web sockets and subscribing to SNS https messages?
Are there alternatives solutions to these which might be more suited for Node.js applications?

